# Hovering rows with the same class in HTML table with CSS only

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I have 2 HTML tables with the same row class names:

```css
.tables {
  display: flex;
}

table {
  margin: 10px;
}

table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr[class^="row-"]:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <table>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td>row 1, col 1</td>
      <td>row 1, col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td>row 2, col 1</td>
      <td>row 2, col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td>row 1, col 1</td>
      <td>row 1, col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td>row 2, col 1</td>
      <td>row 2, col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change background color of rows with the same class name **in both tables** with CSS only (no JavaScript) on mouse hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) which Chrome and Edge now support, presumably with the rest of the browsers to follow:

```css
.tables {
  display: flex;
}

table {
  margin: 10px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.tables:has(tr.row-1:hover) tr.row-1,
div.tables:has(tr.row-2:hover) tr.row-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <table>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td>row 1, col 1</td>
      <td>row 1, col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td>row 2, col 1</td>
      <td>row 2, col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td>row 1, col 1</td>
      <td>row 1, col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td>row 2, col 1</td>
      <td>row 2, col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Would it be possible to match rows with the same class names in both tables without specifying class name directly (e.g. `row-1` and `row-2`) in case I have tables with hundreds of rows?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to do this using :has but I'm not sure that there currently is. You'd need a way to tie the first part of the selector to the second. If something hits me I'll update my answer.